# How can I manage my string parsing issue in haskell

Tags: string, unit-testing, parsing, haskell, functional-programming

I'm new in Haskell and I try to create a parser with different conditions to understand the language.

Here my parser for a String type:

```
parseString :: Parser Haskell
parseString = do
    char '"'
    x <- many $ satisfy (\c -> isAscii c && not (c == '\"'))
    char '"' 
    return $ String x
```

And my unit test

```
it "return substring" $ do
            parse parseLiteral "\"\"\"Hello" `shouldBe` [(String "\"", "Hello")]`
```

I have this parsing issue:

*expected: [("\"","Hello")]*

*but got: [("","\"Hello")]*

I don't know where my error is. Have you an idea ?

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here. You've posted code for `parseString`, but your unit test is for `parseLiteral`.  What's `parseLiteral`?  Also, which parsing library are you using?

Comment: Also, if `parseString` and `parseLiteral` are the same thing, the correct parse looks like it should be `[("","\"Hello")]`.  The tokens `"""Hello` look like a valid empty string literal followed by `"Hello`, and that's what your parser is returning, so maybe it's your unit test that's wrong here.

Comment: It's my own parseur and here my parseLiteral : 
parseLiteral :: Parser KoakValue
  parseLiteral = parseDouble `option` parseInteger `option` parseBool `option`   parseString `option` parseChar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parser seems to work exactly as coded:

1. First, `char '"'` consumes the first quote
2. Then, `many $ satisfy ...` doesn't consume anything, because the next character is a quote, which does not satisfy the predicate
3. Finally, `char '"'` consumes the second quote, yielding an empty string as a result and leaving an unconsumed tail of `"Hello"`

If you want your parser to treat the initial three quotes as a quoted quote, you have to define some strict rules for how that would work.

For example, should four quotes in a row be parsed as two quotes that are quoted on both sides, or should it be one quoted quote with an unconsumed tail consisting of one quote?

What about if there are other characters? Should `"foo"bar"` be parsed as `"foo\"bar"` or as `"foo"` with an unconsumed tail of `bar"`?

In short, there is a good reason why escape sequences exist :-)